# Connection refused when accessing my website with a url and a port number but its fine if accessing it with IP

Tags: apache, cpanel, connections, port-number

I have a cpanel apache website. When i try to access it with url and a port number like mysite.com:3000 it returns connection refused but if I access it with ip like 147.100.xx.xxx:3000 it's working fine. Accessing inside server with localhost:3000 also fine.

I reckon it's not a DNS problem because browsing to mysite.com without port number returns the correct page.

What should I do to allow access with mysite.com:3000?

Comment: I'm not an Apache  expert, but this sounds like a firewall/proxy issue.  I.e., the firewall recognizes the FQDN (even though the name is resolved to an IP) in the header.  THe firewall assumes HTTP(S) but notes that it's to a non standard port and flags it as suspicious (because of the FQDN).  But, when using the IP address, it doesn't include the FQDN in the request header and somehow bypasses a rule that would otherwise block the attack.